# Bash increment a date on Mac OS X

Tags: bash

I am trying to increment date as follows (mac Catalina)

```
DATE=2019-01-01
NEXT_DATE=$(date +%m-%d-%Y -d "$DATE + 14 day")
```

but am getting `date: illegal time format`. How can I increment to the date?

Comment: This code works on GNU but fails for you because you're on macOS. Since bash doesn't support date operations natively, you should include the OS in your question

Comment: @thatotherguy bash printf support date *printf '%(%b %d %Y)T' +14*

Comment: Nice. But does it support parsing so that it can solve's OP's problem natively?

Comment: i did just found -1 somewhere and thought $DATE + 14 would do it, but seems no

Answer (score 3):

In `bash` on Mac OS X, you can do like this:

```
date -j -v +14d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "2019-01-01" +%Y-%m-%d
```